# Why only acute triangles in Fagnano’s Problem?

Tags: geometry

Fagnano’s Problem: To inscribe in a given acute-angled triangle the triangle of minimum perimeter.

Why does the geometric proof through reflection only work for acute triangles?

This website provides some reasoning, but it is really confusing. Here is a quote of the two parts that are confusing.

> [If ∠C = 90∘, then HK intersects ΔABC at C; if ∠C > 90∘,then ΔCHK exists, but it is
>   outside ΔABC :
>   This is where the hypothesis that ΔABC is acute is needed.]
>
> [If ∠C ≥ 90∘, then there is no minimum for P,but P > 2CZ and P can be made arbitrarily close to 2CZ. ]

http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/90.pdf

A picture of the proof I refer to:
[Fagnano's Problem Geometric Proof w/Reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiEQ1.jpg)

Comment: because in obtuse triangle one of the heights will not intersect a side of a triangle

Comment: Why does that make the proof not hold? There is still an orthic triangle that should have the minimal perimeter.

Comment: In an obtuse triangle, the inscribed triangle of minimal perimeter is the height from the obtuse angle - so degenerate

Comment: Please include "the geometric proof through reflection" as part of your question, or provide a link to such, so that we know exactly which proof you mean.

Comment: I have added a picture of the proof to my post.

Comment: The website you link to says,  in the last sentence, without explanation, that there is no inscribable triangle with minimum perimeter in a right or obtuse triangle, but that the perimeter can be made arbitrarily close to $2CZ$. Is that the part you find confusing?

Comment: Yes, that it is the part that confuses me. It also provides some reasoning on the first page, which is also confusing and unclear.

Comment: What part of the reasoning on the first page is also confusing?

Comment: Can you explain the part about the 2CZ please? On the first page, I am confused by the part about acuteness.

Comment: Why was the question put on hold!?

Comment: I personally find this question intriguing. A not-particularly-geometrical thought that I haven't really investigated is that, maybe, the orthic triangle as well as the three degenerate triangles corresponding to altitudes from each vertex, are all "critical" figures (in a vague Calculus sense). Each is sort-of vying to be the minimal-perimeter triangle; when the triangle is acute, the orthic wins, otherwise, one of the degenerates wins, and the transition is a smooth one (the orthic and winning degenerate match when there's a right angle).

Comment: Do you know how this could be proven?

Comment: @Mr.Hax: A Calculus argument would seem to be required to validate the "critical" notion, but such an argument is very ugly. (The beauty of the reflection argument is that it completely avoids Calculus.) If there's any justice, this dynamic should be visible in the geometry, but I'm not seeing it (yet).

Comment: All I need to prove is why the orthic triangle is NOT the triangle of minimal perimeter when the triangle is not acute. This seems like it could be done in a simpler way?

Comment: @Mr.Hax: It does seem like it. :)  I believe, as you seem to, that the geometry is trying to tell us something here. I haven't had an opportunity to investigate what that might be. (I don't know if I'll have such an opportunity anytime soon.)

Comment: Consider the expanded answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an obtuse triangle, the orthic triangle cannot be inscribed, since two of its vertices lie outside the given triangle. Hence the triangle with minimum perimeter inscribable within an obtuse triangle is not the orthic triangle. We'll need an argument and solution different from that of the geometric proof in question.

[edit]: 
[image: Fagnano's problem]
To see that in fact there is no triangle of minimal perimeter inscribable in an obtuse triangle, let triangle $ABC$ have obtuse angle at $C$. Taking $X$, $Y$, $Z$ at random, let $K$ and $H$ be the reflections of $Z$ about $CA$, $CB$ respectively. Let $YX$ in triangle $XYZ$ intersect $CZ$ at $M$, and join $MK$, $MH$.

Then keeping $Z$ fixed while moving $Y$ and $X$ in any manner down toward $A$ and $B$, it's clear that $YZ$ approaches equality with $AZ$, $XZ$ with $BZ$, and $YX$ with $AB$. Hence the perimeter of $\triangle XYZ$ can be made arbitrarily close to $2AB$.

Alternatively, moving $X$ and $Y$ upward toward $C$, then since$$KY+YM\ge KM$$and$$HX+XM\ge HM$$then the perimeter of $\triangle XYZ$$$KY+YX+XH\ge KM+MH$$But by Euclid, *Elements* I, 21$$KM+MH>KC+CH=2CZ$$Therefore, the perimeter $P$ of $\triangle XYZ$ approaches $2CZ$ as a minimum, and$$2AB>P>2CZ$$

And we reach the same conclusion when $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle.

Comment: Why does the inequality 2AB > P > 2CZ mean that there is no triangle of minimal perimeter inscribable in an obtuse triangle?

Comment: Because no matter how small the perimeter is, you can always make it smaller, by moving $X$ and $Y$ a little closer to $C$, and when the perimeter is equal to $2CZ$ it is no longer a triangle but has degenerated into two coincident lines of length $CZ$.

Comment: Why is 2AB > P necessary? Also, how do we get around the fact that Z is fixed (is it because for every Z on AB we will always be able to bring P arbitrarily closer to 2CZ. Sorry if that is a really obvious question.)

Comment: As $Y$ and $X$ move down, at some point angles $ZYA$ and $ZXB$ become obtuse and $ZY$ and $ZX$ start increasing. But $ZY+ZX$ remains less than $AB$ until $Y$ and $X$ coincide with $A$ and $B$, when $ZY+ZX+YX=2AB$. But at that point triangle $XYZ$ has collapsed. So $P$ of triangle $XYZ$ must remain less than $2AB$. Wherever we take $Z$ on $AB$, if we keep it fixed as we move $Y$ and $X$ up toward $C$, the conclusion follows that $P$ is getting smaller until triangle $XYZ$ collapses. But there is no least value for $P$ before that collapse. Another comment to follow may help here.

Comment: But, why is 2AB > P necessary to prove that P has no minimum. (Doesn't it just prove that there is no maximum)

Comment: From an intuitive standpoint, it is clear that moving Y and X closer to CZ brings the lengths of YZ and XZ closer to the length of CZ, but logically why does this happen?

Comment: A similar thing happens with numbers: $\frac{3}{2}>\frac{17}{12}>\frac{99}{70}>\frac{577}{408}>\frac(3363}{2378}...>\sqrt 2$. The sequence is endless; there is no least rational number that is greater than the irrational square root of $2$. So too here, there is no least triangle $XYZ$ that is greater than the degenerate $2CZ$.

Comment: Thanks, my only remaining question is why 2AB > P is necessary to prove that P has no minimum (Does it not just prove that there is no maximum P)

Comment: $2AB>P$ is not necessary. I just thought it was easier to see that $P$ has no maximum, as a warm-up to seeing that it also has no minimum. As for "logically why does this happen,"  isn't it self-evident that $YZ+XZ$ approaches $2CZ$?

Comment: It is self-evident intuitively, but (rigorously) why does it occur.

Comment: How about: "Things which coincide with one another are equal." (Euclid, Elements, Common Notion 4).  Or this: "Quantities, and the ratios of quantities, which in any finite time converge continually to equality, and before the end of that time approach nearer the one to the other than by any given difference, become ultimately equal" (Newton, Principia, Bk I, Lemma 1)

Comment: How do we know that KM + MH > KC + CH

Comment: That's a fair question. See Euclid, Elements I, 21: "If on one of the sides of a triangle, from its extremities, there be constructed two straight lines meeting within the triangle, the straights lines so constructed will be less than the remaining two sides of the triangle, but will contain a greater angle."  The triangle here is $KMH$, and $KC$, $CH$ are constructed within it.  Thus $KC+CH<KM+MH$

Comment: Also, why does this proof not apply to acute triangles. What about this proof relies on the triangles being obtuse or right.

Comment: In an acute triangle $KH$ passes through triangle $ABC$. So $P>KM+MH$, but $KM+MH$ is not always greater than $KC+CH=2CZ$. Since triangle $KCH$ doesn't always fit inside triangle $KMH$, Euclid I, 21 doesn't apply now. $P$ does not remain greater than $2CZ$ as $Y$ and $X$ go up to $C$, but $P$ reaches a minimum value when $Y$ and $X$ lie on $KH$, as the link shows. For then $KY+YM+MX+XH=KM+MH<KC+CH=2CZ$. Hence minimum $P$ for $Z$ anywhere on $AB$ only when triangle is acute. (And minimum of all minima when $CZ$ is perpendicular to $AB$). But in right and obtuse triangles no minimum P exists..

Comment: How can you prove that HK is above the triangle when obtuse and inside when acute?

Comment: When the angle is obtuse, then since the reflection doubles it we get an angle of more than 180 degrees. That puts $HK$ above and outside triangle $ABC$. If the angle is right, doubling makes it exactly 180 and $HK$ passes through $C$ since $HCK$ is a straight line.

Comment: What becomes an angle of more than 180 degrees or exactly 180 degrees, or less than 180 degrees. Which angle that is?

Comment: Angle $KCH$, measured from below.

Comment: Again, double an obtuse angle is > 180--a "reflex angle",-- putting $HK$ above and outside of triangle $ABC$.  But double an acute angle is < 180, making $HK$ pass through $ABC$. How is that not evident?